# How to debug remotely

Tags: android, adb

I have a situation:
1. Samsung 7 has a strange bug in my app.
2. This device is 10000 miles away from me.

What are the opportunities for debugging this device remotely.

When tester on the other side can do everything.

I tried `adb tcpip <port>`
but device ip can be only local(`192.168.....`)

The rude way is to get Android Studio there and install team viewer on the phone. It's not working every time.

And when we have 1 hour intersection it's difficult to support.

Is there any other way?

Comment: so the bug is only in a samsung 7? try to run an emulator with same android version and specs.. that maybe is a temporary solution

Comment: The same version works fine. On Samsung 7 bug reproducec every time!

Answer (score 1):

1. Have your user enable `Developer Options` on the device. You should already know how to do that.
2. See whether the device has `Take Bug Report` and/or `Bug Report Shortcut` settings. If you enabled `Bug Report Shortcut` a `Take Bug Report` option will appear when pressing/holding the power button.
3. Instruct your user to take a bug report -- either through Developer Options, or from the power menu -- as soon as your app crashes.

As for the APK you send to your user, make sure debugging is enabled, so you get all your log messages. If you obfuscate the APK, be sure you keep your mapping files handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some idea of where the bug is happening, an option could be to set up something like http://www.acra.ch/ and send your tester a new apk.

This way when the bug is provoked, given you set up useful log events, you will receive information about the crash or bug. ACRA lets you include the LogCat as well, which is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

-Build APK and send it to the phone. Install and check/try again.

-Create Android Virtual Device identical to the model located remotely, install Samsung Android firmware.

There is no clear solution about debugging out of local network.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like LogmeIn for Android - this way both devices will be in the same network.

Once done, just do usual `adb connect ipadress` If t refuses to do so first, try enabling ADB over WiFi option

Comment: LogmeIn not allows me to do that. But you have a cool idea. It's like hamachi for Android.
I can't find at the moment, but do you know other programs for Android to make with remoted Android + Mac a local network?

Comment: In that case try OpenVPN. It is install-able on Mac as server and there is official client for Android on Play Store. It will take some time to set it up but afterwards you can use it with any device


[Here are some instructions](https://www.stevesell.com/?p=36)
If you don't have external IP, probably DDNS would be fine too

I guess there are some free VPN servers on the Internet so maybe you'll only need to set up two clients (didn't google that)